# extjs remove space between panelheader and border

Tags: css, extjs, panel

there is this tiny white space between the panel header and the border.
does anyone know how to remove it?

```
@include extjs-panel-ui(
$ui: 'dark',
//$ui-header-background-color: #242c7e,
$ui-border-color: #242c7e,
//$ui-header-border-color: #242c7e,
//$ui-body-border-color: #242c7e,
$ui-border-width: 3px,
$ui-border-radius: 3px
//$ui-header-color: white
```

);

[image: screen]

Comment: Which ext version are you using ?